# How to add/remove Select class onClick on dynamically added elements in React

Tags: reactjs, tabs

I'm a beginner to react and trying to create TABS. I wanted to know how to manage states or else click on the particular tab to add "Selected" class and remove the same class from other tabs

You can check my code here
https://codesandbox.io/s/elated-mestorf-005yq

please help

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: I have modified the sandbox code, you can see if it is the effect you want 

https://codesandbox.io/s/cocky-oskar-tdv9n?file=/src/Tabs/Tabs.js

Answer (score 0):

Use the index value of the array as the selected condition

```
class Tabs extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.state = {
      selected: 0
    };
  }

  selectTab = (key) => {
    this.setState({
      selected: key
    })
  };
  render() {
    console.log(data.length);
    return (
      <div className={style.tabsCont}>
        <ul>
          {data.map((val, key) => {
            return (
              <li
                id={`tabs${key + 1}`}
                onClick={(event) => this.selectTab(key)}
                className={this.state.selected === key ? style.selected : ""}
              >
                {val.tabs}
              </li>
            );
          })}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should store your active id as a state. And don't use index as a key.  [code](https://codesandbox.io/s/eloquent-feistel-k0xpm?file=/src/Tabs/Tabs.js)